# SAX Parsing doesn't fill ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, saxparser

I'm sorry for my bad english firstly.

Here is my goal;

I need to read xml (actually from web service but there are some problem with my host and i use direct xml link, as my web services return data) from my link. Then i need to write those data to listView.

And here is my problem;

I read that xml from web link and i think parsed xml. I say like this because when i debug project i can see some data on my GettersSetters variable. But when i send those data to my adapter class, there is no action, i guess. Because i can not see any changes on my listView.

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
XMLGettersSetters data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        SAXParserFactory saxPF = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxP = saxPF.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlR = saxP.getXMLReader();

        URL url = new URL("http://utkuyegen.com/dersProgramiListele.xml");

        XMLHandler myXMLHandler = new XMLHandler();
        xmlR.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xmlR.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("xmlParser", e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    data = XMLHandler.data;
    System.out.println("data = XMLHandler.data");

    try {
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        System.out.println("listView tanımlandı");

        dataAdapter adapter = new dataAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_row,
                data.getDersID(), data.getDersAdi());
        System.out.println("adapter tanımlandı");

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        System.out.println("adapter listView 'e atandı");

        // TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        // textView1.setText(data.getDersID().get(2));

        System.out.println("onCreate son satır");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

}

public class dataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<XMLGettersSetters> {
    // XMLGettersSetters items;
    ArrayList<String> _dID, _dAdi;

    public dataAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> dID, ArrayList<String> dAdi) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this._dID = dID;
        this._dAdi = dAdi;
        Log.d("da", "1");
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
            Log.d("da", "5");
        }

        Log.d("da", "2");
        TextView dersID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dersID);
        TextView dersAdi = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.dersAdi);
        Log.d("da", "3");
        dersID.setText(_dID.get(position));
        dersAdi.setText(_dAdi.get(position));
        Log.d("da", "4");
        return convertView;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

And XMLGettersSetters.java

```
public class XMLGettersSetters {
private ArrayList<String> dersID = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> dersAdi = new ArrayList<String>();

public XMLGettersSetters(ArrayList<String> dersID, ArrayList<String> dersAdi) {
    this.dersID = dersID;
    this.dersAdi = dersAdi;
}

public XMLGettersSetters() {
}

public String getDersID_tek(int i) {
    return dersID.get(i);
}
public ArrayList<String> getDersID() {
    return dersID;
}
public void setDersID(String dersID) {
    this.dersID.add(dersID);
}

public String getDersAdi_tek(int i) {
    return dersAdi.get(i);
}
public ArrayList<String> getDersAdi() {
    return dersAdi;
}
public void setDersAdi(String dersAdi) {
    this.dersAdi.add(dersAdi);
}
}
```

And XMLHandler.java

```
public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    String elementValue = null;
    Boolean elementOn = false;

    public static XMLGettersSetters data = null;

    public static XMLGettersSetters getXMLData() {
        return data;
    }

    public static void setXMLData(XMLGettersSetters data) {
        XMLHandler.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        elementOn = true;

        if (localName.equals("ArrayOfDersProgrami"))
        {
            data = new XMLGettersSetters();
        } else if (localName.equals("dersProgrami"))
        {
            /** 
             * We can get the values of attributes for eg. if the CD tag had an attribute( <CD attr= "band">Akon</CD> ) 
             * we can get the value "band". Below is an example of how to achieve this.
             * 
             * String attributeValue = attributes.getValue("attr");
             * data.setAttribute(attributeValue);
             * 
             * */
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        elementOn = false;

        /** 
         * Sets the values after retrieving the values from the XML tags
         * */ 
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("DersID"))
            data.setDersID(elementValue);
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("DersAdi"))
            data.setDersAdi(elementValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        if (elementOn) {
            elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            elementOn = false;
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, i got some point with my code and debug.

When i debug this codes, i see that i can not understand data.

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfDersProgrami xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <dersProgrami>
    <DersID>0</DersID>
    <DersAdi>0</DersAdi>
  </dersProgrami>
  <dersProgrami>
    <DersID>1</DersID>
    <DersAdi>1</DersAdi>
  </dersProgrami>
  <dersProgrami>
    <DersID>2</DersID>
    <DersAdi>4</DersAdi>
  </dersProgrami>
  <dersProgrami>
    <DersID>3</DersID>
    <DersAdi>9</DersAdi>
  </dersProgrami>
  <dersProgrami>
    <DersID>4</DersID>
    <DersAdi>16</DersAdi>
  </dersProgrami>
</ArrayOfDersProgrami>
```

As you see there is five data but as i said when i debug i see 12 data in my array.
I scope data variable "data = XMLHandler.data;" and i see two arrayList, dersAdi and dersID. Then i scope dersAdi, i see array = Object[12], modCount = 5, size = 5. Then i scope array = Obj.. i see [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, null, null, null, null, null, null, null].

What is that mean? I got 5 datas in my xml but there is 12 datas.

And What i want;
I need some suggestion and i'm close to deadline.

This project is my season

Answer (score 0):

It’s a normal behavior I think, you are debugging an ArrayList<> so what you see are the variables into the class ArrayList as you can see there is an array into that initially has size 12 and null cells and also there is an integer that holds the real number of your items (modCount)

so don’t worry about that the class ArrayList is well developed  :P

to get sure from what I say  you can debug any other ArrayList you will get same behavior.

EDIT:

try to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`after setting your adapter to listview

Comment: ArrayList is OK. Thank you for your reply.

But what about listView's doen't fill? What should i do?

Comment: I added that you said line but there is no response